# Aligning multiple authors (with pictures) in a grid

Tags: positioning, titles, titling

Working on a project with 4 members, I'd like to align the authors in an "even" way on the title page. I'm thinking a simple 2 by 2 "grid" would likely look best, but I'm having some issues getting it to work.

The current code gives me the three first authors on one line, with the fourth on a separate line.

The `titling` package seems like it could be used for what I want by encasing the author part in some kind of table, but even just including it gives me the error `Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }`. As far as I can tell, this error is because of there being images within the `\author` command (Note that due to a requirement of this particular assignment, the images are needed).

Any help would be appreciated!

```
\documentclass[11pt, titlepage, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \title{Project report}
    \author{A. Uthor \\YYMMDD-XXXX \\ \includegraphics{photo}
    \and A. Uthor \\YYMMDD-XXXX \\ \includegraphics{photo}
    \and A. Uthor \\YYMMDD-XXXX \\ \includegraphics{photo}
    \and A. Uthor \\YYMMDD-XXXX \\ \includegraphics{photo} }
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the authors in a nested `tabular` to arrange them properly:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, titlepage, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\newcommand{\authorblock}[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}
\title{Project report}
\author{\begin{tabular}{c@{\qquad}c}
  \authorblock{A. Uthor \\ YYMMDD-XXXX \\ \includegraphics[width=50pt,height=80pt]{example-image-a}} &
  \authorblock{A. Uthor \\ YYMMDD-XXXX \\ \includegraphics[width=50pt,height=80pt]{example-image-b}} \\[\bigskipamount]
  \authorblock{A. Uthor \\ YYMMDD-XXXX \\ \includegraphics[width=50pt,height=80pt]{example-image-c}} &
  \authorblock{A. Uthor \\ YYMMDD-XXXX \\ \includegraphics[width=50pt,height=80pt]{example-image-a}}
\end{tabular}}
\begin{document}
  \maketitle
\end{document}
```